# How to automatically redirect NET Core library version

Tags: .net-core

For example, I have trouble similar to this

Error   BC32207 The project currently contains references to more than one version of 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore', a direct reference to version 6.0.1.0 and an indirect reference to version 6.0.6.0. Change the direct reference to use version 6.0.6.0 (or higher) of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. BackendAPI  G:\Projects\ChestMax\BackendAPI\BackendAPI\Controllers\ContainerController.vb   17  Active

How is possible resolve this issue once and for any future of this project?

[Dll hell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh5eY.png)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc32207

Comment: my project used dozens of third party library, for example Pomelo. Of course nobody of company produced this library has no opportunity to follow MS and to recompile each days or each week that library to new and new trash version of last MS library. Therefore (for example) Pomelo library require 6.0.1 version of EF, other third party library require other version of EF. And this is long time project for years and I want to solve this issue today once and for whole future program lifetime.